# Order of executed threads

Tags: java, android

Visually, I'm expecting my app to show four Toasts in the following order:

1. createToast("start of delayed RandomCue Method");
2. createToast("start of delay");
3. createToast("end of delay");
4. createToast("end of delayed RandomCue Method");

However, the resulting order is:

1. createToast("start of delayed RandomCue Method");
2. createToast("end of delayed RandomCue Method");
3. createToast("end of delay");
4. createToast("start of delay");

My overall goal is to have a program that displays an image and changes ever 3 seconds. The player can press a button and the image changes for 1.5 seconds. Therefore, there are two methods, one to change picture using countdowntimer and another to change picture using onClick method corresponding to imagebutton.

The problem I'm running into is the code provided in the link (method called from within an onclick method) is supposed to change the image, set a bool value to false, wait 1.5 seconds, and then change the same bool value back to true.

While the bool value is true, the method that changes the pictures is supposed to be skipped but that's not the case and I don't know why but I think it's something to do with the code in the gists I created below.

So the issue I have is when the button is clicked, the image changes as expected but it sometimes changes again too quickly due to the first method not recognizing that the player responded and thus shouldn't change image yet.

```
 public void delayedRandomCue(final long a){
    didPlayerRespond = true;
    createToast("start of delayed RandomCue Method");
    randomCue();
    Thread delay = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                createToast("start of delay");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                createToast("end of delay");
                didPlayerRespond = false;
            }
        }
    };delay.start();

    createToast("end of delayed RandomCue Method");
}
```

https://gist.github.com/cjayem13/d32446ceb8c6d9626c68#file-easyfragment-Java
https://gist.github.com/cjayem13/d32446ceb8c6d9626c68

https://gist.github.com/cjayem13/d0a0b124dfe17666be25#file-easyfragment-Java
https://gist.github.com/cjayem13/d0a0b124dfe17666be25

```
 onclick(){
delayedRandomCue(final long a)
}

 randomCue();
    Thread cueThread = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
                try {
                    while (fComm.fragmentGetTimerBool()) {
                        if(!didPlayerRespond) {
                            if (decTime > 1000) {
                                Thread.sleep(decTime);
                            } else {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            }
                            decTime -= 50;
                            randomCue();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    saveScore();
                }
            // turn into end of all pics triggers bonus sTimerOn = false;  fComm.fragmentScoreResponse(100);
            //createToast("Bonus for completing all possible answers");
        }
    }; cueThread.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void delayedRandomCue(final long a){
        didPlayerRespond = true;
```

**this happens first**

```
 createToast("start of delayed RandomCue Method"); 
        randomCue();
        Thread delay = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
```

**This happens in the background, asynchronously.**

```
                try {
                    createToast("start of delay");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
```

**This happens in the background, after asynchronously running and completing**

```
                    createToast("end of delay");
                    didPlayerRespond = false;
                }
            }
        };delay.start();
```

**This comes second because it is executed synchronously with the rest of the method.**

```
 createToast("end of delayed RandomCue Method");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer you question about the order of the toasts, but are you sure , when you say

> The problem I'm running into is the code provided in the link (method
>   called from within an onclick method) is supposed to change the image,
>   set a bool value to false,wait 1.5 seconds, and then change the same
>   bool value back to true.
>
> While the bool value is true, the method that changes the pictures is
>   supposed to be skipped but that's not the case and I don't know why
>   but i think it's  something to do with the code in the gists I created
>   below.

that this is the case?

It looks more like , if the boolean is set to false, the other method that changes the pictures needs to be skipped, and as long as it is true, it needs to periodically change the pictures.

Try that, and maybe your image won't change very quickly after the user did trigger the onClick.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Currently, I have two methods where the first changes a picture every 3 seconds and a second method that changes the picture upon the user clicking button. In order to make the first method not change the picture immediately after second method changed it, the first method only runs when a bool is true. when second method runs it makes bool false for 5 seconds but the first method still runs before 5 seconds is up.  I'm not sure that I understand what you are telling me to try.